# Вывод строк через цикл while до определенного слова

Tags: python, циклы, while

есть небольшой список, который представлен в виде песни.

```
['Идет по свету менестрель, поет не "тра-ля-ля",',
 'Он песню бережно несет про дочку короля,',
 'За что бродячий менестрель ей стал однажды люб,',
 'Пускай узнает вся земля, узнает добрый люд.',
 'Вот перед ней, вот перед ней, вот перед ней',
 'Какую трель рассыпал менестрель.',
 'Два озера - твои глаза, я в них окончу путь,',
 'Я просто выбрать не могу, в каком мне утонуть']
```

Условие, что надо написать код, который выводит на экран строки песни из списка до тех пор, пока не натолкнется на строку, содержащую заданное слово (например короля). Итоговая выдача должна выглядеть с окончанием выбранного слова и троеточием
При решении нельзя использовать готовые индексы элементов списка, то есть вручную найти номер строки, содержащей заданное слово, и просто вывести на экран элементы до нее.
Не могу понять, как правильно через цикл while прогнать список. Пытался представлять его в форме str. , а слово поставить как переменную, но все тщетно. Буду очень признателен, если объясните/напишите логику

Comment: *Пытался представлять его в форме str. , а слово поставить как переменную* - код в студию

Comment: Понимаете, я только недавно начал изучать python и все статьи, что я встречал с циклом while представлены в формате Int. Мне непонятна сама логика, как это представить через списки с текстом и чтобы это было поделено. Тело должно выполняться, пока условие истинное
х = "слово"
y = str(список)
while x in y:
Здесь я уже понимаю, что пишу идиотизм и просто стопорюсь. Пытаюсь в методы на строках, но тоже выходит какая-то ерунда.

Comment: Ну так откройте любой учебник. Что-бы пояснить как делать вашу задачу вам надо либо прочитать пару страниц из него, либо нам их сюда переписать. Там все элементарно -  но надо подробно разобраться, что такое строка и что такое список.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста ваш код, ведь учебные задания допустимы здесь только при условии, что вы их сами пытались решить.

Answer (score 3):

Если необходимо выводить все слова до встречи с нужным словом, то можно попробовать вот так:

```
lst = ['Идет по свету менестрель, поет не "тра-ля-ля",',
 'Он песню бережно несет про дочку короля,',
 'За что бродячий менестрель ей стал однажды люб,',
 'Пускай узнает вся земля, узнает добрый люд.',
 'Вот перед ней, вот перед ней, вот перед ней',
 'Какую трель рассыпал менестрель.',
 'Два озера - твои глаза, я в них окончу путь,',
 'Я просто выбрать не могу, в каком мне утонуть']


word = 'ей'
n = 0
i = 0

while n<len(lst):
    if word.upper() in lst[n].upper().replace(' ', ''):
        lst_row_with_word = lst[n].split(' ')
        i = len(lst_row_with_word)-1
        while i > 0:
            if word.upper() not in lst_row_with_word[i].upper():
                lst_row_with_word.pop(i)
            else:
                lst_row_with_word[i] = '...'
                print(' '.join(lst_row_with_word))
                break
            i = i - 1
        break    
    print(lst[n])
    n = n + 1
```

Вывод:

```
Идет по свету менестрель, поет не "тра-ля-ля",
Он песню бережно несет про дочку короля,
За что бродячий менестрель ...
```

В случаях когда `word` ни разу не появляется в списке, вывод представит собой все элементы списка `lst`

Comment: вывод должен заканчиваться указанным словом и многоточием

Comment: @Эникейщик Переделал код по вашему комментарию, в начале не учел этот момент в вопросе